# Is there any way to extract frames from video stream and process it real time in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, video-streaming

I want to extract frames from live video stream using windows phone 8. I'm grabbing my video stream from a device via bluetooth connection. Also I want to do some image processing with the extracted frames. But this process should run on background and should notify user along with defined situations. I searched though the internet with my requirements, but didn't find any solution that could be use to handle that kind of scenario.

So please let me know, is it possible to implement that kind of application using windows phone 8 SDK? If so, please kind enough to provide some details and directives that I should concern. Otherwise please let me know what are the major issues with my scenario.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What do you mean by process in the background? If the app isn't running, you won't have access to the device. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202962(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Hi @WiredPrairie, Actually I want to run separate process to process my video stream. It should run even user navigates to another app or start screen.

Comment: That's not supported. You can have background tasks, but they are intentionally very limited in terms of what they can do and the amount of impact they have on battery life/CPU.